# Get JSON from Api - WPF App

Tags: wpf, api

I am trying to get data from a Web Api.  I do an async call to the web api in order to get data back. 
The client need to be authorize so I inject the token in the header.

Here is my method which call the button.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //I checked the token and is good
        var accessToken = token;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5001/movies/");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
          new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = client.BaseAddress })
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("get");
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            MessageBox.Show(content);
        }
    }
```

API : http://localhost:5001/movies/get

Api is returning a list of movies and is working without [Authorize]

I always get back a 401 but I don`t understand why?

Edit 1: The same api is working fine when I try to get data from another client (e.g: website)

Edit 2: Authorize atribute

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
[Route("movies")]
public class MoviesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/get")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new[]
        {
            new { Id = 1, Title = "Never Say Never Again"},
            new { Id = 2, Title = "Diamonds Are Forever "},
            new { Id = 3, Title = "You Only Live Twice "}
        });
    }
}
```

Edit 3: This is from web api Startup.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(
        IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.JwtAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                 {
                     options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000"; // Auth Server
                     options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // only for development
                     options.ApiName = "fiver_auth_api"; // API Resource Id
                 });

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Authority is on port 5000 and I run it in the same time as the we api. n that port is the Identity Server(login to authorize api- from here is coming the token.)

Edit 4:

```
public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app, 
        IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

Comment: Can you update the question with code snippet where you applied [Authorize] attribute?

Comment: First looks like forward slash in "/get" is extra. [Route("get")] should be enough. Second can you share the code where you are calling AddPolicy method something like:  auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());

Comment: I assume Authorization service is also added using services.AddAuthorization. Can we get that line in question along with AddAuthentication(...) that is already added.

Comment: I really hope all my edits will help to clarify my question.

Comment: I believe you are missing services.AddAuthorization(...) in ConfigureServices method. I've added following line of code for JWT bearer based authentication:  services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
            {
                auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()                 .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
            });

Comment: That didn`t helped. I have in DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization "Bearer token". I was thinking that the token is not injected in the header, but it is. I am new to wpf so maybe there I am missing something,

Comment: The code written in WPF/C# to call the get method is fine. Though it can be improved as you are instantiating `httpClient` object despite having initialized  `client` object already. This is just for clean code. Even with this code you shouldn't get 401 since you are using `client` object against which Authorization token is already added in header. The only thing that I'm suspicious about is the token, maybe it's expired or not correct.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but I checked the token and I added to expire in one day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171012/discussion-between-azaz-ul-haq-and-alexandra-damaschin).